# Using FileTransfer to download files in the background on a mobile application packaged with phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, mobile, download

I have packaged my jQuery/javascript application with phonegap for Android, and later plan to do this for iOS/BlackBerry. In this project, I implemented the FileTransfer.download function from the phonegap API to download a file from the server. The function is working successfully, but it blocks me from navigating to other pages within the app until the download is complete.

Maybe I'm missing something in the documentation: what's the best way to get FileTransfer.download to work in the background so that I can freely navigate page to page? Is it possible without resorting to device-specific code?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I'm settling for is creating a plugin to call native code that does the downloading. In Android for example, I can create an AsyncTask to do the downloading in a phonegap plugin. I guess I'll be required to do something similar in iOS/BlackBerry/etc. Still welcoming others' solutions